# Recursive __dict__ call on python object?

Tags: python

Is there a clean way to have **dict** called on all attributes of a python object?  Specifically, when I call **dict** on a my object, I get this:

```
{'edges': [<dawg.Edge instance at 0x107aa0200>,
           <dawg.Edge instance at 0x10a581a70>,
           <dawg.Edge instance at 0x10656a680>]}
```

but I'd like that output to be the instance's **dict**() instead of the instance description.

Edit: I guess I should clarify that I'm trying to JSONify the object, so I need type(obj['edges'][0]) to be a dict.

Comment: Define `__repr__()` on the class.

Comment: __repr__() has to return a string

Comment: Well, I'm trying to JSONify it, so I need the type to actually be a dict, not a string.

Comment: you could eval a carefully constructed string into a dict, not that this is the best idea ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the **repr** solution would be cleaner, but you can also get what you want by adding this line after getting the dictionary you describe above (im calling it `d1`)

```
d2 = {'edges' : map(lambda x: x.getDict(), d1['edges'])}
```

OR with list comprehension instead of map

```
d2 = {'edges' : [i.getDict() for i in d1['edges']]}
```

If you can describe for me what you want a little more I'll try to either implement getDict or write something more in that lambda, but I'm not sure enough about what you're going for.  Is it the dictionary of all of edges fields?

Comment: Actually, yours is much simpler.  I thought there would be some fancy pythonic way to do it, but at this point I just want it to work.

Comment: `map(operator.methodcaller('getDict'), d1['edges'])`

Answer (score 0):

You could give your object a method, called something like `expanddicts`, which builds a dictionary by calling `x.__dict__` for each of the relevant things. This seems better than trying to mess around with the built in dict type and `__dict__` property.